# Swiper js slider loading on homepage but not children page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, swiper.js

I currently have 4 swiper instances running on my homepage that works perfectly fine. I use 1 of these sliders on all children pages within my site as well called "partners-slider". Up until today it worked fine but now it has become broken on all children pages. No idea why it randomly broke. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Libraries used:

Jquery 3.5.0 
Swiper 6.4.9

Error received:
[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4hpM.png)

html snippet:

```html
<div class="partners-slider">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptPartners" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <%# Eval("content") %>
        </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>
```

JS for initializing swiper:

```html
var swiper4;
swiper4 = new Swiper('.partners-slider', {
slidesPerView: '1.5',
grabCursor: true,
spaceBetween: 15,
init: true,
loop: true,
keyboard: {
  enabled: true,
},
navigation: {
  nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
},
breakpoints: {
  576: {
    slidesPerView: '2.75',
    spaceBetween: 15,
  }, 
  992: {
    noSwiping: true,
    grabCursor: false,
    slidesPerView: '3.75',
    spaceBetween: 15,
  },      
}
});
```

Comment: did you update any lib (jquery or swipper) before the errors appear?

Comment: No, I currently use cdns for both libraries

Comment: Actually, I just noticed they committed a new version today actually, I will try to roll it back to 6.4.8 and see if it works, thanks for the heads up, will post if it works!

Comment: Confirming that worked, warning to anyone using swiper 6.4.9 it could cause breakage, marking complete thanks again.